# RXSwift first element of one observable after result of other observable

Tags: rx-swift

I am quite new in the reacitve world and now I have a problem:

I have two functions that returns observables:

```
func connect() -> Observable<Connection>
```

and

```
func execute(_ statement: Statement) -> Observable<Result>
```

What I now need to do is, that `connect` has to run before `execute` and then I have to return the result of `execute`...

What I thought I will do is to run the `execute` function inside of the `map` function of the observable returned by `connect`, like this:

```
public func executeFetch(_ query: Statement) -> Observable<Result> {
    return self.connect()
    .map({ (connection) -> Result in
        return execute(query) // here is my problem because execute returns an Observable<Result>.
    })
}
```

But because `execute` returns an `Observable<Result>` I get an `Observable<Observable<Result>>`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map`, try using `flatMap`.  `flatMap` allows you to chain the previous result into another Observable, whereas `map` is more of a direct transformation of values (e.g. turning an `Observable<A>` into an `Observable<B>`.

There's nothing wrong with performing a bunch of synchronous work inside `map`, especially if you use a `Scheduler` to ensure that that work is done on an appropriate thread (e.g. `.subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(globalConcurrentQueueQOS: .Background))`), but if you're trying to weave a second Observable into your chain then `flatMap` would be the idiomatic way to do it.